# Min and max terms and Karnaugh maps

Tags: minimax, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

Could anyone explain what is the importance of max and min terms in boolean algebra and uses of Karnaugh maps. I feel like confused in those titles.

Comment: is this programming related?

Comment: You might want to consult your [favorite search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=minterm).

Comment: @AkashGupta it's part of Digital Systems. It is related to programming indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Minterms use SOP (sum of products) - and are represented by Sigma

Maxterms use POS (product of sums) - and are represented by Pi

Minterms are classified when the output of the truth table row is a 1, while maxterms capture the 0's.

The representation is also different, minterms look like: (AB)+(CD) while maxterms look like (A+B)(C+D).

K-Map:

SOP uses the K-map normally and captures the 1s. When the 1 (header) is constant, the variable will be A for example, but if the 0 is constant, it would be A' (A Bar).

POS does the exact opposite (captures all the 0s). Keep in mind that when a 0 is constant, it will be A for example, but when a 1 is constant (it's inverted) and becomes an A'

[image: kmap 4 variable]